# How to use Pycharm with an ssh tunnel?

Tags: ssh, pycharm, ssh-tunnel

MYsql workbench has this amazing option of creating a SSH tunnel i.e connect using "Standard TCP/IP over SSH".

Can this same be created for PyCharm?

Alternatively, How do I configure an SSH tunnel such that all traffic through my local laptop should goto remote machine and from there it should reach the external world?

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to View > Tool Windows > Database.
2. Once the Database panel is open, click on the + button, followed by Datasource > [RDBMS of your Choice] in order to add your database to the panel controller.
3. Fill out your credentials for your database admin access under "General" or "Database" (depends on the RDBMS you chose).
4. Fill out your SSH/SSL credentials.
5. Click 'Test Connection'
6. Upon successful connection, click 'Apply'
7. Click 'Ok'
8. Navigate/Edit your database inside of PyCharm!

Note: You may be asked to install drivers as you progress through these instructions.

Let me know if this helps. There are a variety of ways that you can use SSH Tunneling in PyCharm, but you asked for it's relation to MySQL Workbench, so I described instructions access a remote database.

Comment: I am not able to find the Database option in my pycharm.. Is it because of community edition?

Comment: Will this make any connection made through MySQLdb connect statement use this ssh tunnel?

Comment: Yes, the community edition is very limited in it's features, as you can see here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

If you partition a Vagrant server or a Droplet on DropOcean, you could potentially SSH into it and connect to a database running there!
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/running-ssh-terminal.html